# Why is mmap returning a size of zero?

Tags: python, linux, embedded-linux, mmap

I'm working on a beaglebone (running Angstrom Linux) and trying to use Python's `mmap` module to gain read and write access to the `/dev/mem` file.

However, for some reason, the code below prints a value of zero. I'm fairly new to mmap and I'm not sure if there is something obvious I am missing.

```
from mmap import mmap

mmap_offset=0x44c00000
mmap_size=0x48ffffff-mmap_offset

with open("/dev/mem", "r+b") as f:
    testMap=mmap(f.fileno(),mmap_size,offset=mmap_offset)

print testMap.size()
print testMap[0]
```

returns:

```
0
8
```

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#mmap.size) say *"Return the length of the file, which can be larger than the size of the memory-mapped area."* Perhaps this is because all device nodes have an apparent size of 0 according to `stat()`? What happens if you actually try to get data out of the mmap object?

Comment: What @cdhowie said. Also, as an aside, I think you mean `0x49000000` rather than `0x48ffffff` because with `0x48ffffff` you will end up not mapping the last byte of the last page.

Comment: I've updated the code, which i thinks answers your question... it looks like there are values in the memory map. I'm not familiar with `stat()`

Comment: @Chris `stat()` returns information about filesystem inodes.  For example, `ls` uses `stat()` to determine the apparent size of files.  Device inodes *always* have an apparent size of 0.  (If you are curious why, consider this: what size should `/dev/zero`, `/dev/kbd`, and `/dev/urandom` report?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because device inodes like `/dev/mem` report an apparent size of 0 when queried by [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).  This is simply how special device nodes are implemented, as it's not usually useful to ask a device node how large it is.  (Consider `/dev/zero`, `/dev/kbd`, `/dev/urandom`, and any device node that is used for communication and not data storage, such as device nodes representing photo scanners or input devices.)

You should still be able to retrieve data from the mmap handle.